# Why do I get this error when catkin_make my package?

Tags: ros, urdf, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Linking CXX executable /home/joao/catkin_ws/devel/lib/testbot_description/parser /opt/ros/hydro/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, void*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)' /opt/ros/hydro/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, void*, ros::console::levels::Level, std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [/home/joao/catkin_ws/devel/lib/testbot_description/parser] Error 1 make[1]: *** [testbot_description/CMakeFiles/parser.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2 Invoking "make" failed
```

[ROS Hydro  and Ubuntu 12.04]

I am trying to follow the urdf parser tutorial.

My `testbot_description` package has a `/src/parser.cpp`   file  and a `/urdf/my_robot.urdf`  file

Both are identical to the ones suggested by the tutorial page. (I already copied and pasted the code to make sure).

This is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(testbot_description)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS urdf)



## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES testbot_description
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS urdf
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


add_executable(parser src/parser.cpp)
target_link_libraries(parser ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

And this is my `package.xml`:

```
<package>
  <name>testbot_description</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>The testbot_description package</description>


  <maintainer email="joao.cicero@ifce.edu.br">Joao Cicero</maintainer>

  <license>BSD</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>urdf</build_depend>
  <run_depend>urdf</run_depend>

  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->

    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140116/why-do-i-get-this-error-when-catkin_make-my-package?/) by [Joao Ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/13366/joao-ferreira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2014-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-15**:
Please also post your package.xml

**Comment by [Joao Ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/13366/joao-ferreira/) on 2014-03-15**:
Thanks, BennyRe.  I just added it. I hope it will help.

**Comment by [Joao Ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/13366/joao-ferreira/) on 2014-03-15**:
I just realized that when I comment the code that calls for initFile()  I get rid of this error and I am able to build my package.

In my parser.cpp , if I keep the

"
if (!model.initFile(urdf_file))
{
ROS_ERROR("Failed to parse urdf file");
return -1;
}
"

the error appears again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I don't know why, but when I git cloned the **robot_model** package to my catkin workspace, instead of just installing it using **apt-get**  I finally managed to build my **testbot_description** package.

Does anyone know why? At least I can proceed with the urdf tutorials, now, and I hope this will help others.

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src

$ git clone https://github.com/ros/robot_model

$ cd ~/catkin_ws

$ catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [Joao Ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/13366/joao-ferreira/) with karma: 81 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0